# how to get dropdownlist value and pass to controller via ActionLink?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I need to send the value of a dropdown list to my controller using an Actionlink.

I am using this code:

**send list to view from controller:**

```
ViewBag.Frecuencies = new SelectList(db.Frecuencies, "FrecuencyID", "Description");
```

**show list in View:**

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Description", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) ViewBag.Frecuencies,new { name="Frecuency"})
```

and I want to send the value from dropdown with the ActionLink as parameter:

```
@ActionLink("ActionName","Controller",new {**ParameterName=DropdownValue**})
```

some help?

Comment: First of all, you should use a Model, not a ViewBag for passing data from Controller to View and vice versa.

Comment: I don't think you can do this without using JavaScript. You have to get the selected value from the list and then add it in to the `<a>` tag that the `@Html.ActionLink()` generated.

Comment: Thank you!! , finally i've used the binding model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do this without using JavaScript. You have to get the selected value from the list and then add it in to the `<a>` tag that the `@Html.ActionLink()` generated.

First I would add some id's to those `Html` helper methods.

```
@Html.DropDownList("Description", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Frecuencies, new { name = "Frecuency", id = "Frecuency-id" })

@Html.ActionLink("ActionName", "Controller", new { paramName="", id="action-link-id"})
```

Then you proceed to JavaScript. Here is how you could go about this using jQuery:

```
var selectedValue = $("#Frecuency-id").val();

$("#action-link-id").attr("paramName", selectedValue);
```

Of course you would still have to execute this code every time your selected value changes.

```
var valueList = $("#Frecuency-id");

    valueList.on("change", function () {
        var selectedValue = $("#Frecuency-id").val();

        $("#action-link-id").attr("paramName", selectedValue);
    });
```

The code should look somewhat like what I've described above.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have this setup:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Description", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Frequencies, new { id = "Frequency" })

@Html.ActionLink("Link Text", "ActionName", "ControllerName", null, new { id = "Link" })
```

Then you can manipulate `href` attribute of the link with query string:

```
$('#Frequency').change(function () {
    var ddlValue = $(this).val();
    var url = $('#Link').attr('href');

    $('#Link').attr('href', url + '?ParameterName=' + ddlValue);
});
```

If the link already has parameter value like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link Text", "ActionName", "ControllerName", new { ParameterName = "OtherValue" }, new { id = "Link" })
```

Then you can replace parameter value as follows:

```
$('#Frequency').change(function () {
    var ddlValue = $(this).val();

    $('#Link').attr('href', function () {
        return this.href.replace("OtherValue", ddlValue);
    });
});
```

Note that parameter value supplied with `ActionLink` is processed server-side, which creates anchor tag with `href` attribute containing URL with controller name, action name and query string parameters as in example below:

```
<a id="Link" href="/ControllerName/ActionName?ParameterName=[DDLValue]">Link Text</a>
```